# Module specific error handling in Angular

Tags: angular, error-handling

I am making use of the [ErrorHandler](https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler) in Angular. It works fine if i am working with only one module. When i am using multiple modules and want to use different error handlers in a specific child module, it does not work. Only the parent error handler is invoked.

```
RootModule
|--> provides CustomErrorHandler1
|    
|--> ChildModule1
|    |--> provides CustomErrorHandler2
|
|--> ChildModule2
     |--> provides CustomErrorHandler1
```

If an error occures in ChildModule1 or ChildModule2 the error is always handled by the CustomErrorHandler1 instance of RootModule.

I am using lazy-loading to load those modules. Providing different instances of the same service works for all @Injectable()s except for the error handler.

Is it possible to provide those ErrorHandlers so that the errors in each module will be handled by the ErrorHandler provided in their module definition?

I created a sample repository at [github](https://github.com/karsunke/angular-error-handler). It can be run via `ng serve`. If you click on "child1" an error is thrown by Childmodule1 and if you click on "child2" an error is thrown by Childmodule2.

Comment: Can you post code of all 3 modules?

Comment: I added a sample repository.

Comment: I think when you define an error handler inside of your `root` module, it will override all other error handlers in it's children, try removing your handler on `app.module.ts` and just extend from `ErrorHandler` from inside of your children

Comment: I made a branch with your suggestions. https://github.com/karsunke/angular-error-handler/tree/nikola_gavric If you remove the root error-handler, there is no error handling at all.

Comment: I'll clone the repo now

Comment: You need to add permissions so I can push to that branch @FranziskusKarsunke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, that ErrorHandling just works for RootModules and the Angular Team is not planning to change that:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22197

Comment: They didn’t exactly say that. Someone posted a question that wasn’t really a big report and the issue was closed after someone else tried to help them. There’s no discussion of a feature request nature here.

Answer (score 3):

After some research I found out that

> **ErrorHandler** => Provides a hook for centralized exception handling.

So I registered only 1 `ErrorHandler` which intercepts all `Exceptions` then I've delegated the error to the `component based ErrorHandlers` and handled the data inside of them. Every `child` component will have it's own `Error` and based on `instanceof` we are delegating error to the appropriate `ErrorHandler` inside of the `component`.

**Note:** The downside of this is that any `Error` that passes `error instanceof Error` check will be delegated to the `Global registered handler` aka one inside of `app.module.ts`

Also I know that this approach might not be the best, but there isn't a possibility of registering multiple `ErrorHandlers` that are `per component` but rather one `Global` one and then handling everything inside of it. Hope that this can help you resolve the issue in a proper way.

Also I've updated the [`nikola_gavric`](https://github.com/karsunke/angular-error-handler/tree/nikola_gavric) branch so you can see what I did there

Answer (score 0):

Could you share the code from the Modules???

From what you point it doesn't make any sense since Angular when routes are lazyLoaded, creates a hierarchy of injectors in compilation. That should create the effect that your are looking for.

My suggestions are:

- Check that your Modules are really been LazyLoaded. The result you are getting is consistent with an eagerLoaded App.
- Check that your provide token is correct for example you should be doing:
  `{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: CustomErrorHandlerX }`

Comment: I can assure that they are lazy loaded and that they are provided in the same way. All Services have their own instances in their corresponding modules. Only the error handling does not work.

Comment: Did you check that you are using the `{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: CustomErrorHandlerX }` for every module where you want a different ErrorHandler?

Comment: I added a sample repository there you can see, that everything is provided correctly and lazyloaded correctly.